# Counting the number of integer sequences

Tags: combinatorics

Count the number of sequences of integers, `a(1), a(2), .... a(n)`, containing n positive integers such that`1<=a(i)<=m, for all 1<=i<=n` and `max_value - min_value = q`, where *max_value* means the highest integer in the above sequence and similarly for *min_value*. Note that repetition is allowed.

**NOTE1** : Just to avoid confusion, sequence 1,2,3 and 3,2,1 are different.

**NOTE2** : In case someone computes the count to be equal to

`nC2 * 2! * (m-q) * (q+1)^(n-2)`  [nC2 = n choose 2]

which, bytheway, seems pretty logical at the first glance, please note that it is incorrect as we are overcounting; many cases are counted more than once.

Comment: I get $[m-q][(q+1)^n-2q^n+(q-1)^n]$ assuming $0\lt q\le m$; of course the answer is $m$ if $q=0$. Does this seem to produce the correct numbers? If so, I'll post the formula and derivation as an answer.

Comment: This seems to be correct. Kindly post the explanation so that I can cross-check/understand the derivation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $1\le q\le m-1$. We can pick the minimum value in $m-q$ ways, i.e., any element of the set $\{1,2,\dots,m-q\}$.

Now we count the number of sequences of length $n$ with minimum value $x$ and maximum value $x+q$. There are $(q+1)^n$ sequences with values in the interval $[x,x+q]$. Among these there are $q^n$ that miss $x$, there are $q^n$ that miss $x+q$, and there are $(q-1)^n$ that miss both $x$ and $x+q$. By the in-and-out principle, the number of sequences that hit both endpoints is $(q+1)^n-2q^n+(q-1)^n$.

Hence the number of sequences satisfying the conditions stated in the question is $[m-q][(q+1)^n-2q^n+(q-1)^n]$ provided $0\lt q\le m$. (The formula is obviously correct in the case $q=m$ which was not discussed.)

Answer (score 1):

I would use inclusion/exclusion.  We can pick the minimum value in $m-q$ ways, so without the restriction that we use the top and bottom there are $(m-q)(q+1)^n$ sequences.  Now we delete those without the minimum appearing, which is $(m-n)q^n$ and those without the maximum appearing, another $(m-n)q^n$, but we have removed the ones without the minimum and maximum twice, so we add back in $(q-1)^n$ getting $(m-q)[(q+1)^n-2q^n+(q-1)^n$] for a final count

Comment: If $q=1,n=2,m=3$ your final count is $10$, but it should be $4$. I believe I gave the correct answer in my comment.

Comment: This is incorrect. The answer for n=4 m=3 q=2 should be 50. Or take a more trivial example of n=2 m=2 q=1, whose answer should be 2.

Comment: @bof:  yes, a couple off-by-ones.  fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: You are still missing a pair of brackets: each term should have an $m-q$ factor.