# Number of ways of arranging numbers with given max difference

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, permutations

How many ways are the there to arrange **n** numbers out of **m** numbers (1 to m) so that the difference between the max and min numbers of those **n** numbers is **D** which is given.

For example :

n = 4

m = 3

D = 2

Number of ways = 50

Comment: I suppose you want to know the cardinality of
$$A = \{(a_1, \ldots, a_n) : |a_i - a_{i-1}| \leq D \wedge a_i \in \{1,\ldots, m\} \forall\ i\}$$?

Comment: Not exactly. The difference between the max number and the min number should exactly be D. For other pairs, it can be <=D

Comment: Oh, that makes it a lot easier.

Comment: I get $108$ for $(n,m,D) = (4,3,2)$ instead of $50$

Comment: 1 1 1 3 - 4, 
1 1 2 3 - 12,
1 2 2 3 - 12,
1 2 3 3 - 12,
1 1 3 3 - 6,
1 3 3 3 - 4

Comment: A [similar problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518153/counting-the-number-of-integer-sequences) was posted a few hours ago, with the same example. The only difference seems to be, in the earlier version, the max and min values were given, instead of just their difference.

Answer (score 0):

The min number will be between $1$ and $m - D$; the max between $1+D$ and $m$. First find out $|A_i|$ with
$$A_i := \{a | \min_k a_k = i \wedge \max_k a_k = i+D\}$$
We chose the position of one min and one max index, giving
$$n \cdot (n-1)$$
ways. For the remaining $n-2$ we have $D+1$ options each (between $i$ and $i+D$ incl.), thus
$$|A_i| = n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (1+D)^{n-2}$$
This is independent of $i$ and so
$$|A| = \sum_{i=1}^{m-D} |A_i| = (m-D) \cdot |A_1| = (m-D) \cdot n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (1+D)^{n-2}$$

---

**EDIT** Okay, this double-counts a few. I'll think about it for a moment...